# Existential types and monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, existential-type

Context: I'm trying to produce an error monad that also keeps track of a list of warnings, something like this:

```
data Dangerous a = forall e w. (Error e, Show e, Show w) =>
    Dangerous (ErrorT e (State [w]) a)
```

i.e. `Dangerous a` is an operation resulting in `(Either e a, [w])` where `e` is a showable error and `w` is showable.

The problem is, I can't seem to actually run the thing, mostly because I don't understand existential types all that well. Observe:

```
runDangerous :: forall a e w. (Error e, Show e, Show w) =>
    Dangerous a -> (Either e a, [w])
runDangerous (Dangerous f) = runState (runErrorT f) []
```

This doesn't compile, because:

```
Could not deduce (w1 ~ w)
from the context (Error e, Show e, Show w)
...
`w1' is a rigidtype variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor
    Dangerous :: forall a e w.
                 (Error e, Show e, Show w) =>
                 ErrorT e (State [w]) a -> Dangerous a
...
`w' is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for
    runDangerous :: (Error e, Show e, Show w) =>
                    Dangerous a -> (Either e a, [w])
```

I'm lost. What's w1? Why can't we deduce that it's `~ w`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An existential is probably not what you want here; there is no way to "observe" the actual types bound to `e` or `w` in a `Dangerous a` value, so you're completely limited to the operations given to you by `Error` and `Show`.

In other words, the only thing you know about `w` is that you can turn it into a `String`, so it might as well just be a `String` (ignoring precedence to simplify things), and the only thing you know about `e` is that you can turn it into a `String`, you can turn `String`s into it, and you have a distinguished value of it (`noMsg`). There is no way to assert or check that these types are the same as any other, so once you put them into a `Dangerous`, there's no way to recover any special structure those types may have.

What the error message is saying is that, essentially, your type for `runDangerous` claims that you can turn a `Dangerous` into an `(Either e a, [w])` for *any* `e` and `w` that have the relevant instances. This clearly isn't true: you can only turn a `Dangerous` into that type for *one* choice of `e` and `w`: the one it was created with. The `w1` is just because your `Dangerous` type is defined with a type variable `w`, and so is `runDangerous`, so GHC renames one of them to avoid name clashes.

The type you need to give `runDangerous` looks like this:

```
runDangerous
  :: (forall e w. (Error e, Show e, Show w) => (Either e a, [w]) -> r)
  -> Dangerous a -> r
```

which, given a function which will accept a value of type `(Either e a, [w])` for *any* choices of `e` and `w` so long as they have the instances given, and a `Dangerous a`, produces that function's result. This is quite hard to get your head around!

The implementation is as simple as

```
runDangerous f (Dangerous m) = f $ runState (runErrorT m) []
```

which is a trivial change to your version. If this works for you, great; but I doubt that an existential is the right way to achieve whatever you're trying to do.

Note that you'll need `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` to express the type of `runDangerous`. Alternatively, you can define another existential for your result type:

```
data DangerousResult a = forall e w. (Error e, Show e, Show w) =>
   DangerousResult (Either e a, [w])

runDangerous :: Dangerous a -> DangerousResult a
runDangerous (Dangerous m) = DangerousResult $ runState (runErrorT m) []
```

and extract the result with `case`, but you'll have to be careful, or GHC will start complaining that you've let `e` or `w` escape — which is the equivalent of trying to pass an insufficiently polymorphic function to the other form of `runDangerous`; i.e. one that requires more constraints on what `e` and `w` are beyond what the type of `runDangerous` guarantees.

Comment: Is there a better (or more idiomatic) way to do this? I really just want an error monad that comes with some warnings.

Comment: Why not just define the type as `Dangerous e w a`? There's no need for existentials here, if I understand what you're trying to achieve (which I quite likely might not).

Comment: I have a few modules that all throw their own errors and warnings, and they're handled at the top level. The top level only needs to print them, but it's annoying to say `Dangerous OptError OptWarning [Option]` in the options module and `Dangerous TemplateError TemplateWarning Template` in the templates file, when they will all just be `show`n. I'm trying to remove a lot of boilerplate and learn a little something, it's certainly not essential.

Comment: @So8res Yes, quit trying to use existentials.  Either include the type variables in the type constructor, or pick concrete types.  Or maybe some of each.  It looks like you really want e to be a type variable in the type constructor, and you really want w to just be String.

Comment: @So8res: Well, if all you're going to do with them is `show` them, you could just use Strings like Carl said. Alternatively, you could use those types internally inside a module, but have your exported interface use a String-based `Dangerous` type, and translate at the borders. I would just define a type synonym for each module's `Dangerous` monad. But even if it is prohibitively awkward, it's a bit of a moot point, as existentials can't really help you at all here :)

Comment: @Carl that's the easy way to get it working, but it's already working and I want to reduce the boilerplate and learn a bit more about type-level programming in haskell. (This is just a good excuse to learn by doing.) So "do it the easy way" isn't the answer I'm looking for. I'd entertain the idea of `data Failure = forall e. (Error e, Show e) => Failure e` and defining `Dangerous` without existentials, then I'd have `data Dangerous a = Dangerous ErrorT Failure (State [Warning] a)` but I have trouble figuring out how to define `instance Monad Dangerous`

Comment: What I would do is define a `liftDangerous :: (Show e, Error e, Show w) => Dangerous e w a -> MainDangerous a`, where `type MainDangerous = Dangerous String String`, or whatever most-general error and warning types you use at the top layer. Then you can consume `Dangerous` values from all kinds of disparate sources in a general way, and have their errors and warnings automatically integrated into your main monadic context.

Comment: @So8res: Your dedication to learning more about Haskell's advanced type system features is admirable, but it would be better directed at trying to reduce boilerplate in areas where it is actually possible to apply the relevant features.

Comment: @So8res Features should be used when they better express what you actually mean.  If you want a type to be polymorphic in a way that lets you recover the type used, you need to give it a type variable.  As far as I can tell, that's the meaning of e.  If you want String, say String.  That's all w is, in any usable sense.  It shouldn't be controversial that cramming in random features that don't clarify your meaning is a bad approach.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured out what I was floundering after:

```
data Failure = forall e. (Error e, Show e) => Failure e

data Warning = forall w. (Show w) => Warning w

class (Monad m) => Errorable m where
    warn :: (Show w) => w -> m ()
    throw :: (Error e, Show e) => e -> m ()

instance Errorable Dangerous where
    warn w = Dangerous (Right (), [Warning w])
    throw e = Dangerous (Left $ Failure e, [])
```

(`instance Monad Dangerous` and `data DangerousT` help too.)

This allows you to have the following code:

```
foo :: Dangerous Int
foo = do
    when (badThings) (warn $ BadThings with some context)
    when (worseThings) (throw $ BarError with other context)

data FooWarning = BadThings FilePath Int String
instance Show FooWarning where
...
```

and then in your main module you may define custom instances of `Show Failure`, `Error Failure`, and `Show Warning` and have a centralized way to format your error messages, for example

```
instance Show Warning where show (Warning s) = "WARNING: " ++ show s
instance Show Failure where ...

let (result, warnings) = runDangerous function
in ...
```

Which, in my opinion, is a pretty cool way to handle errors and warnings. I've got a working module that's something like this, now I'm off to polish it up and maybe put it on hackage. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but `data Warning = forall w. (Show w) => Warning w` is equivalent to `data Warning = Warning String`; you might as well have your `warn` function call `show` on the warning value. Existentials are *really not what you want* here.

Comment: I appreciate you're trying to apply a cool type system feature, but the only effect it's having here is to make the code more complex without adding any functionality whatsoever.

Comment: Here's some more material to help explain: [1](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FAQ#How_do_I_make_a_list_with_elements_of_different_types.3F), [2](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) — I've seen a good explanation of exactly why not to use something like `data Foo = forall a. (Show a) => Foo a`, too, but unfortunately can't find the link right now.

Comment: Thanks. I'm beginning to realize why existentials aren't what I'm looking for. (I can be a bit stubborn.) The (inteded) point was to allow custom `instance Show Warning`s, allowing you to append "WARNING: " or "Warning: " or nothing at your discretion and not need to worry about constancy. That of course lead to orphan instance warnings, which lead me to reading up a bunch on orphan instances, and I'm beginning to see the point. (I'm stubborn, not stupid \smileyface).

Comment: Hey, if I hadn't gone through a stage where I tried to decompose every problem into a typeclass and an existential for that typeclass, I wouldn't be so quick to dissuade others from using them :) Orphan instances are nasty, nastier still when they're in the same codebase... you might want to consider passing a record with functions to format errors and warnings to any restructured `runDangerous` you create as an alternative.

Comment: Yeah, after reading up on them they look pretty hairy. I've settled on `data Exit = Stop String | Failure String | Die String Int` with a general `exit :: Exit -> IO a` in the errorable clas and further `throw :: (Show s) -> s -> IO a` where `throw = exit . Failure . show` and so on. It lets me define my own `instance show` error classes in each module that use some context to make the strings, then lifts them all into one data type.

Comment: Yep, that solution seems good to me — though if I *had* to pick a nit, it would be that `Show` instances should produce valid Haskell code, and so you technically want your own typeclass there :)

Comment: Cool. https://github.com/Soares/Dangerous.hs/blob/master/src/Control/Dangerous.hs, if you're curious. Thanks for all the help!